# Send Servlet action With href Link and value

Tags: java, html, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to send a post method to servlet. How it works is it will check the action string which then triggers a command `DeleteCommand`and object in table is clicked then it takes the Id of the Reg object and deletes it from database..

so this is my servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
     String action = request.getParameter("action");
    System.out.println(action);
    if (action != null) {
        Command command = new CommandFactory().createCommand(action);
        if (command != null) {
            command.execute(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my command Factory and the command class it would trigger based on action string:

```
 public Command createCommand(String actionString) {
    Command command = null;
    System.out.println(actionString);
    //Instantiate the required Command object...
    if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("login")) {
        command = new LoginUserCommand();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("manageRegistrar")) {
        command = new ManageRegistrarCommand();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("modifyReg")) {
        command = new ModifyRegistrarCommand();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("logout")) {
        //command = new LogoutUserCommand();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("something")) {
        //command = new ManageRegistrarCommand();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
        command = new DeleteRegistrarCommand();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("changePassword")) {
       // command = new ChangePasswordCommand();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("verifyEmail")) {
        //command = new VerifyEmailCommand();
    } else if (actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("resendVerificationMail")) {
        //command = new ResendVerificationMailCommand();
    }else if(actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("modify")){
        //command = new ModifyUserCommand();
    }else if(actionString.equalsIgnoreCase("addRegistrar")){
        //command = new CreateUserCommand();
    }
    //Return the instantiated Command object to the calling code...
    return command;// may be null
}
```

And this is the command I'm currently trying to get the actual parameter value to:

```
public class DeleteRegistrarCommand implements Command {

@Override
public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("regId"));
    //System.out.println(userIdList.get(0));
    UserServices userservice = new UserServices();
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    try {
        if (userId > 0) {
                Registrar registrar = userservice.getRegById(userId);
                if (userservice.delete(registrar.getRegId())) {
                    session.setAttribute("status", 0);
                    session.setAttribute("statusMessage", "Delete Success");
                } else {
                    session.setAttribute("status", 1);
                    session.setAttribute("statusMessage", "Delete Failed");
                }                
        } else {
            session.setAttribute("status", 6);
            session.setAttribute("statusMessage", "Ohoooo no.. Nothing to Delete.. ha ha ha");
        }
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ProcessResult.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    } catch (ServletException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DeleteUserCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        session.setAttribute("status", 4);
        session.setAttribute("statusMessage", ex.getMessage());
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ProcessResult.jsp");
        try {
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException | IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(DeleteUserCommand.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
    }

}
```

}

OK all of these should be working fine (Hopefully).I just have a problem on the client side (JSP Page). I'm trying to send the action type and the value needed by command to my servlet... this is what i have on my `href` but doesn't seem to be right.

so This is it :

```
            <td class="text-center"><a href="WebActionServlet?action=delete?regId=<%=deleteId%>"><samp class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></samp></td>
```

but this doesn't seem to be working and when i click on it i just shows me a blank page and the actual action is not performed.. Does anyone know how do perform this using the href link or is they a better way maybe java script or ajax method to be used to perform this and get id and send action based on that table data link ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `?regId` should be `&regId`. Only the first parameter is delimited with `?`. If you use your debugger, set a breakpoint in your servlet and you can step through the code.

Comment: Use & to separate multiple parameters in url

"WebActionServlet?action=delete&regId=<%=deleteId%>"